# Class could not be converted to string

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I'm trying as a school assignment building a code for a customer list for a tire company. I have made everything work but i still need a function to be able to update a single customer and also echo a string with the specific id of each post in the .txt file. Here is all my code, because when i tried writing out each id from the array i got this:

Object of class Customer could not be converted to string in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/douglas/classes_serialisering.php on line 51

This is the code i used $key(".$obj
") . ....

Here is all the code for the program:

First: classes_serialisering.php

```
<?php
//
// Registrera alla klassfiler som behövs.
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});
global $company;
$company = new Company("Ragnars Däckhotell");

//
// Lägg till lagerpost i textfilen
if(isset($_REQUEST["addPart"])){
if(strlen($_REQUEST["customername"])>0){
$company->addCustomer($_REQUEST["customername"],                 $_REQUEST["customertfn"], $_REQUEST["customerepost"],   $_REQUEST["tirebrand"], $_REQUEST["status"]);
//
//Spara information till filen med lagerinformationen.
    file_put_contents("../objdata.txt",serialize($company-      >getCustomerList()));
 }
 unset($_REQUEST["addPart"]);
 header("Location: classes_serialisering.php");
 exit();
 }
 //
 // Radera en post i lagerregistret
 if(isset($_REQUEST["delPart"])){
 $company->removeCustomer($_REQUEST["delPart"]);
 //
 // Spara all ny information till textfilen med lagerinfon.
 file_put_contents("../objdata.txt",serialize($company- >getCustomerList()));
 unset($_REQUEST["delPart"]); // Disable button press
 header("Location: classes_serialisering.php");
 exit();
 }
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html>
 <head>
    <title> Webb 2 M3 </title>
    <meta charset=utf-8/>
 <style>
    body {font: Verdana; font-size: 1em;}
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="" method="post">
    <p>
 <?php
 //
 // Skriv ut alla poster i registret kopplade till array id.
 foreach($company->getCustomerList() as $key => $obj){
 echo "<br/>" . $key."$obj .<br>". $obj->getcustomername() . ", " .        $obj->getcustomertfn() . ", " . $obj->getcustomerepost() . ", " . $obj- >gettirebrand() . ", " . $obj->getstatus() . ", " . $obj->getdate() .
 " <a href='classes_serialisering.php?delPart=$key'>Radera " . $obj-     >getcustomername() . " </a>";
 }
 ?>
    </p>
    <p>
        Namn: <input type="text" name="customername" /><br/>
        Telefonnummer: <input type="text" name="customertfn" /> <br/>
        E-post: <input type="text" name="customerepost" /> <br/>
        Märke & Dimension: <input type="text" name="tirebrand" /> <br/>
        Status: <input type="text" name="status" /> <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="addPart" value="Lägg Till Kund"/>
    </p>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is company.class

```
<?php
interface RegistrerCustomer {
function addCustomer($customername, $customertfn, $customerepost,       $tirebrand, $status);
function getCustomerList();
}

class Company implements RegistrerCustomer { 
protected $companyname = '';
private $CustomerList = array();

function __construct($companyname){
    $this->foretag = $companyname;

//Hämta textfil med kundlistan.
    if(file_exists("../objdata.txt"))
        $this->CustomerList =        unserialize(file_get_contents("../objdata.txt"));
}
function setCompanyname($companyname){
    $this->Companyname = $companyname;
}
function getCompanyname(){
    return $this->Companyname;  
}
function addCustomer($customername, $customertfn, $customerepost,     $tirebrand, $status){
    $this->CustomerList[] = new Customer($customername, $customertfn,   $customerepost, $tirebrand, $status, Date('c'));
}
function getCustomerList(){
    return $this->CustomerList;
}
function removeCustomer($ind){
    unset($this->CustomerList[$ind]);
}
}

?>
```

Customer.class.php:

```
<?php
//
// En klass för all information som skall kunna lagras i textfilen med       lagerinformationen
abstract class Customerpost {
abstract public function __construct($customername, $customertfn,         $customerepost, $tirebrand, $status, $datum);
abstract function setcustomername($customername);
abstract function getcustomername();

abstract function setcustomertfn($customertfn);
abstract function getcustomertfn();
abstract function setcustomerepost($customerepost);
abstract function getcustomerepost();
abstract function settirebrand($tirebrand);
abstract function gettirebrand();
abstract function setstatus($status);
abstract function getstatus();
abstract function setdate($datum);
abstract function getdate();
}
//
// En extension för klassen ovan
 class Customer extends Customerpost { 
protected $customername = '';
protected $customertfn = '';
protected $customerepost = '';
protected $tirebrand = '';
protected $status = '';
protected $date = '';

function __construct($customername, $customertfn, $customerepost,     $tirebrand, $status, $datum){ 
    $this->customername = $customername;
    $this->customertfn = $customertfn;
    $this->customerepost = $customerepost;
    $this->tirebrand = $tirebrand;
    $this->status = $status;
    $this->date = $datum;
}
function setcustomername($customername){
    $this->customername = $customername;
}
function getcustomername(){
    return $this->customername;
}
function setcustomertfn($customertfn){
    $this->customertfn = $customertfn;
}
function getcustomertfn(){
    return $this->customertfn;
}
function setcustomerepost($customerepost){
    $this->customerepost = $customerepost;
}
function getcustomerepost(){
    return $this->customerepost;
}
function setPnr($pnum){
    $this->tfn = $customertfn;
}
function getPnr(){
    return $this->customertfn;
}
function setEpost($email){
    $this->customerepost = $customerepost;
}
function getEpost(){
    return $this->customerepost;
}
function settirebrand($tirebrand){
    $this->tirebrand = $tirebrand;
}
function gettirebrand(){
    return $this->tirebrand;
}
function setstatus($status){
    $this->status = $status;
}
function getstatus(){
    return $this->status;
}
function setdate($datum){
    $this->date = $datum;
}   
function getdate(){
    return $this->date;
}
}
?>
```

Any ideas of why it does not work to echo each id? And also, how should i make a function to be able to update each post by a button to the right of each post after filling out the form, then pressing 'update', like the 'Radera' button i have now, which is 'delete' in swedish.

Comment: Did you really mean to echo `$obj`? It appears to be an object.

Comment: Since i assigned every post in the array like this, yes.                                        foreach($company->getCustomerList() as $key => $obj)

Answer (score 0):

As this hasn't been answered and you have clearly made a lot of effort, your issue lies with this line:

```
echo "<br/>" . $key."$obj .<br>". $obj->getcustomername() . ", " .$obj->getcustomertfn() . ", " .$obj->getcustomerepost() . ", " . $obj- >gettirebrand() . ", " . $obj->getstatus() . ", " . $obj->getdate() ." <a href='classes_serialisering.php?delPart=$key'>Radera " . $obj->getcustomername() . " </a>";
```

Specifically, you have done:

`echo "<br/>" . $key."$obj .<br>"`

(which looks like a typo)

This means you are echoing the key and the value, but, the value is actually a `Customer` object which `echo` will not  attempt to convert to a string unless you provide a `__tostring()` method in your `Customer` class. http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

You should either remove the `$obj` in that part of your code *or* provide a `__toString()` method in your `Customer` class so that `echo` knows how to convert the `Customer` object to a string.

I would also suggest choosing a consistent naming convention for your methods, usually either [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) or [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case), as this will make your code more readable.

Please ask the second part of your question separately as it's a different issue, and you have provided a lot of code to look through, which we all have to try to decipher. I *think* you are asking how to [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php), update and then re-[serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) your object, so those pages will be a good starting point.